# How to use POST method in rest-assured and fetch the value from its response

Tags: junit, jersey, rest-client, rest-assured

I want to test POST method using rest-assured. I want to fetch the value returned in the response and use the value as path param in another GET method. Can anyone please provide sample code for POST method and how to fetch the value from response.? Thanks in advance.

Edit :

```
RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    builder.setBody(input);
    builder.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = builder.build();
    given()
    .spec(requestSpec)
    .when()
    .post("myURL");
```

This is the approach i am using for POST and PUT method. My response will produce a JSON output like

```
{
"Name": "value",
"email": "abc@xxx.com"}
```

i want to fetch the value of name and use it as a queryparam for another GET method. Can anyone help me to solve this problehow to get the value from JSON response and assign it to a variable ?

Comment: Any solution for this friends?

Comment: I want to use JSON for post method and i want to fetch the value from the json response

Comment: You should really see the tutorials for rest-assured for this.  If you get stuck at a certain point this site will help you but we're not here to give you the basics

Comment: @Wiggles.Added my sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be covered in the tutorial, but did you try something like this?

```
String json = given()
.spec(requestSpec)
.when()
.post("SomeKindOfUrlHere")
.asString();

System.out.println("Name: " + from(json).get("Name"));
System.out.println("Email: " + from(json).get("email"));
```

Comment: hi todd. Really thanks for your suggestion.i solved this problem already by using JsonPath.